# Узнать, унаследован ли переданный объект от интерфейса

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

У меня есть один обобщенный интерфейс, от которого наследованы несколько интерфейсов.

Так же имеется конструктор который принимает интерфейс типа `IVLCObject`, т.к. он использует обобщенный интерфейс, и я могу из него извлечь необходимый указатель на неуправляемый объект, встал вопрос об уменьшении вызовов с разными типами, и подмена объекта на обобщенный интерфейс.

На данный момент я подумал что можно так проверить на факт присутствия интерфейса в объекте. Как правильно проверить наследован ли объект обобщенного интерфейса от `IVLCMedia`?

Обобщенный интерфейс:

```
public interface IVLCObject : IDisposable
{
    IntPtr ObjectHandle { get; }

    bool IsInvalid { get; }
}
```

2 интерфейса наследника:

```
public interface IVLCMedia : IVLCObject
{
    Uri Location { get; }
    void AddOption(string mediaOption);
    long Duration { get; }
    ...
}
```

```
public interface IVLCMediaPlayer : IVLCObject
{
    IVLCMedia Media { get; set; }
    bool Play();
    void Pause();
    void Stop();
    ...
}
```

А так же конструктор класса принимающий такой интерфейс:

```
internal class VLCMediaPlayer
    : VLCObject<VLCMediaPlayer.libvlc_media_player_release_t>, IVLCMediaPlayer
{
    public VLCMediaPlayer(IVLCObject vlcObject)
        : base(libvlc_media_player_new(vlcObject,
            vlcObject.GetType().GetInterface("IVLCMedia") != null), libvlc_media_player_release)
    {
    }

    ....

    private static IntPtr libvlc_media_player_new(IVLCObject vlcObject, bool fromMedia = false)
    {
        return Environment.Is64BitProcess
            ? fromMedia
                ? libvlc_media_player_new_from_media64(vlcObject.ObjectHandle)
                : libvlc_media_player_new64(vlcObject.ObjectHandle)
            : fromMedia
                ? libvlc_media_player_new_from_media32(vlcObject.ObjectHandle)
                : libvlc_media_player_new32(vlcObject.ObjectHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос заставил меня засомневаться, но разве `Type.GetInterfaces()` не возвращает **все** интерфейсы, которые реализует или наследует объект?

Comment: Именно так, но я использую другой метод `.GetInterface(string)` который вроде бы как ищет определенный интерфейс.

Comment: По логике вещей, он также обладает этим свойством. Или у Вас что-то не работает? Или вопрос именно в том, как правильнее проводить проверку?

Comment: Да, вопрос в том как правильно проводить проверку, т.к. критично время определения типа объекта.

Comment: Извините, что не по теме, но что-то как ни загляну в Ваши вопросы, у Вас всегда какая-нибудь тема, завязанная на представлении объектов в памяти, работе с COM-объектами и так далее. И все на C#... Радует, конечно, такая преданность этому замечательному языку, но Вы не думали, что на языке вроде того же С++ мороки со всем подобным было бы на порядок меньше?)

Comment: И уже по теме: вопрос интересный. Сам всегда проверял через GetInterface(s), но в ситуациях, где время выполнения не является критичным. Попробую поискать что-нибудь на сей счёт, да проведу бенчмарки, так что найдём ответ и для Вас, и для будущих поколений)

Comment: `но Вы не думали, что на языке вроде того же С++ мороки со всем подобным было бы на порядок меньше?` все дело в саморазвитии и поиске тех или иных решений с которыми сталкива(юсь/лся).

Comment: Таки похвально тогда, что я могу сказать) Просто я думал, что Вы все это делаете в рамках некой оплачиваемой работы, ставя при этом для себя цели, за достижение которых Вам никто, увы, не доплатит)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Итак, давайте посмотрим, какие варианты решения Вашей проблемы имеются в арсенале `.NET`:

---

### #0: Type.GetInterface

В своем коде Вы использовали метод [`Type.GetInterface(string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterface?view=netframework-4.7.2), так что логично начать именно с него

```
public static bool Implements<UInterface>(this object Object) => 
    Object.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(UInterface).Name) != null;
```

Судя по [одной из реализаций данного метода](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/rttype.cs,f8efe9e9e24d4a74), под катом чаще всего все равно сокрыто итерирование по всем наследуемым интерфейсам с последующей проверкой на соответствие условию (в нашем случае - полное совпадение имени)

Так что отсюда логичным будет перейти к следующему варианту:

---

### #1: Type.GetInterfaces

Мы можем получить список реализуемых нашим объектом интерфейсов и пройтись по нему сами, используя метод [`Type.GetInterfaces()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfaces?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
public static bool Implements<UInterface>(this object Object)
{
    Type interfaceType = typeof(UInterface);
    return Object.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(interfaceType);
}
```

На этом, думаю, хватит эксплуатировать идею с проходом по списку всех интерфейсов, так что попробуем нечто иное:

---

### #2: Pattern matching

Как вариант, мы всегда можем проверить возможность приведения объекта к нужному нам типу интерфейса с помощью сопоставления шаблонов, так что метод можно переписать вот так:

```
public static bool Implements<UInterface>(this object Object) => Object is UInterface;
```

Код стал раз в 10 элегантнее, чем все то, что мы до сих пор видели выше
Но так ли хорош этот код в плане быстроты исполнения? Увидим ниже)

---

### #3: Type.IsAssignableFrom

По аналогии с сопоставлением шаблонов, мы можем проверить,

> можно ли присвоить экземпляр указанного типа экземпляру текущего типа

с помощью метода [`Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
public static bool Implements<UInterface>(this object Object) => 
    typeof(UInterface).IsAssignableFrom(Object.GetType());
```

Это может быть особенно полезно в тех случаях, когда на момент компиляции тип интерфейса нам неизвестен (о сопоставлении шаблонов при таком раскладе, понятное дело, речи не идет)

---

### #4: Type.IsInstanceOfType

Как мне кажется, метод [`Type.IsInstanceOfType(Object)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.isinstanceoftype?view=netframework-4.7.2), используемый в этом абзаце, имеет не совсем верное название (я бы ожидал от него строгой проверки соответствия типов), однако результат его исполнения показывает

> входит ли текущий объект `Type` в иерархию наследования объекта, представленного параметром, или является ли текущий объект `Type` интерфейсом, реализуемым параметром

А сие как раз нам и нужно, так что в очередной раз перепишем метод:

```
public static bool Implements<UInterface>(this object Object) => 
    typeof(UInterface).IsInstanceOfType(Object);
```

---

### #5: Здравствуйте, я ваша <s>тетя</s> таблица методов

Ну не был бы я собой, если бы не добавил к ответу что-нибудь эдакое!

Пока я вчера писал этот пост, у меня формировалась следующего рода идея: информация обо всех реализуемых интерфейсах лежит прямиком в виртуальной таблице методов объекта. Так почему бы не попробовать вытянуть ее прямиком оттуда?

Собственно, это я и сделал)

Для начала стоит разобрать представление `.NET`-объекта в памяти
На сей счет в интернете я нашел следующую прекрасную картинку, которая проиллюстрирует сие Вам как нельзя лучше:

[image: method table]
<sub>*(Если Вы первоначальный автор этой картинки, то я ни коим образом не претендую на ее авторство. Она лишь служит той цели, которую Вы в нее и заложили: просвещает людей)*</sub>

Что же тут происходит?

- В первом столбике мы видим представление самого объекта в памяти.
  К слову, указатель на объект приводит нас прямиком к ссылке на таблицу методов
- В таблице методов нас интересует графа **"Pointer to Interfaces"**,
  которая направит нас прямо к сектору, где записаны runtime-указатели
  всех реализуемых объектом интерфейсов
- Список интерфейсов идет до начала списка, собственно, методов,
  присущих объекту. Так что интересующая нас зона располагается ровно
  до него. Адрес начала списка методов можно достать из графы
  **"Pointer to Methods"**
- Каждая графа занимает по 4 байта, так что спокойно может быть интерпретирована как `IntPtr`

Думаю, разобрались!
Так что вот Вам код реализации поиска искомого интерфейса в таблице методов объекта:

```
public static bool Implements<UInterface>(this object Obj)
{
    unsafe
    {
        // Получим MT Pointer нашего интерфейса
        IntPtr iMTPointer = typeof(UInterface).TypeHandle.Value;

        // Получим ссылку на объект
        TypedReference trObj = __makeref(Obj);
        IntPtr ptrObj = **(IntPtr**)&trObj;

        // Получим ссылку на таблицу методов объекта
        void* methodTable = (*(IntPtr*)ptrObj.ToPointer()).ToPointer();

        // Перейдем к разделу реализуемых интерфейсов
        IntPtr* interfaces = (IntPtr*)((IntPtr*)methodTable)[9].ToPointer();
        // А также получим число реализуемых интерфейсов
        int count = ((ushort*)methodTable)[7];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++interfaces, ++i)
            // Разыменовываем текущий указатель и сверяем, 
            // равно ли его значение искомому
            if (*interfaces == iMTPointer)
                return true;

        // Если в цикле ничего найдено не было, возвращаем false
        return false;
    }
}
```

Это работает и работает на удивление быстро!
Понятное дело, что тягаться с `is` из метода **#2** никто не сможет (он на уровне `IL` представлен всего одной командой), однако сей метод выигрывает по скорости у всех остальных!
Подробнее - ниже

---

На сием методы (коие мне известны) заканчиваются, так что подведем итоги, прогнав все это дело через benchmark:

```
|               Method |       Mean |      Error |     StdDev |     Median | Ratio | RatioSD | Rank |
|--------------------- |-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|------:|--------:|-----:|
| #0 CompileTimeString | 379.808 ns |  7.3281 ns |  7.5254 ns | 380.619 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 |    6 |
|     #0 RunTimeString | 428.352 ns | 12.5997 ns | 36.7538 ns | 419.475 ns |  1.15 |    0.08 |    7 |
|                   #1 | 200.056 ns |  5.1834 ns | 14.8722 ns | 191.448 ns |  0.53 |    0.05 |    5 |
|                   #2 |   8.363 ns |  0.0859 ns |  0.0803 ns |   8.321 ns |  0.02 |    0.00 |    1 |
|                   #3 |  62.209 ns |  0.6735 ns |  0.6300 ns |  62.278 ns |  0.16 |    0.00 |    4 |
|                   #4 |  41.878 ns |  0.3018 ns |  0.2675 ns |  41.813 ns |  0.11 |    0.00 |    3 |
|                   #5 |  16.117 ns |  0.2061 ns |  0.1827 ns |  16.001 ns |  0.04 |    0.00 |    2 |
```

P.S. - В таблице значение графы `Method` соответствует номеру метода в данном ответе (метод **#0** был протестирован отдельно для строки с именем, которая задана на момент компиляции, а также для той, которая получается непосредственно из типа интерфейса)

Итак, волею судеб получилось так, что Вы случайно избрали самый медленный из возможных вариантов, так что вопрос Вы задали не зря :D

Как очень наглядно видно из таблицы, самым лучшем решением является сопоставление шаблонов, которое отрабатывает почти в 50(!) раз быстрее, нежели вариант под номером **0**!
Так что, возвращаясь к вопросу *"так ли хорош этот код в плане быстроты исполнения"*, отвечу:
- Да, так же хорош, как и прост в написании

---

Вывод из всего, что было сказано выше, прост:

- Если у Вас уже есть объект и Вы просто хотите проверить, наследует ли
  он желаемый интерфейс (известный на момент компиляции) - используйте
  сопоставление шаблонов (**#2**)
- Если же тип неизвестен, но у Вас по-прежнему на руках есть объект, то
  используйте мой метод (**#5**) или метод [`Type.IsInstanceOfType(Object)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.isinstanceoftype?view=netframework-4.7.2) (**#4**)
- Ну а если Вы не оперируете объектом и/или тип интерфейса заранее не
  удосужился стать известным, то метод
  [`Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.7.2) (**#3**) - Ваш верный выбор!

---

Надеюсь, данный ответ помог Вам разрешить Вашу проблему!
Удачи в Ваших свершениях!

Comment: Все же `expr is type` это не сопоставление шаблонов, это тестирование на совместимость типов. Сопоставление шаблонов это `expr is type varname`: [is (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: безусловно согласен, просто термин «сопоставление шаблонов» слышал абсолютно каждый, а чего-то настолько элегантного для «testing for type compatibility»  в русском (да и вообще) я сходу не придумал ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Интересное пятое решение :) Кстати, проверить пуст ли указатель, или ссылается на нулевой адрес можно с помощью `null`.

Comment: @LLENN: а ведь правда хД Что-то если я начал извращаться, то этот процесс уже не остановить хД Сейчас подправлю, спасибо